# Usbioctl.h USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION struct with zero-elements array

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, usb

So, we've got a program from our professor, that supposedly will enumerate through the devieces connected to usb hub. I won't get into the specifics, cause that's not what my question is about.

This is one of the functions, and in specified line I've got a 2233 error which states: *"'identifier' : arrays of objects containing zero-size arrays are illegal.
Each object in an array must contain at least one element."*

```
void getDSPortData(HANDLE devHandle, UCHAR connectionIndex)
{
    ULONG bytesReturned;
    bool success;
    PUSB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION pConnectionInformation = NULL;
    ULONG nBytes = sizeof(USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION) + sizeof(USB_PIPE_INFO) * 30; //15 EP IN + 15 EP OUT
 
    pConnectionInformation = new USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION[nBytes]; //error 2233
    pConnectionInformation->ConnectionIndex = connectionIndex;

    success = DeviceIoControl(devHandle, IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION, pConnectionInformation, nBytes,
        pConnectionInformation, nBytes, &bytesReturned, NULL);

    if (!success) {
        delete[] pConnectionInformation;
        return;
    }

    (...)
    delete[] pConnectionInformation;
}
```

So I checked the usbioctl.h header file:

```
typedef struct _USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION {
    ULONG ConnectionIndex;  /* INPUT */
    /* usb device descriptor returned by this device
       during enumeration */
    USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR DeviceDescriptor; /* OUTPUT */
    UCHAR CurrentConfigurationValue;/* OUTPUT */
    BOOLEAN LowSpeed;/* OUTPUT */
    BOOLEAN DeviceIsHub;/* OUTPUT */
    USHORT DeviceAddress;/* OUTPUT */
    ULONG NumberOfOpenPipes;/* OUTPUT */
    USB_CONNECTION_STATUS ConnectionStatus;/* OUTPUT */
    USB_PIPE_INFO PipeList[0];/* OUTPUT */
} USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION, *PUSB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION;
```

As it seems, the problem seems to stem from the PipeList[0] thing. So, is it even legal to type something like this? As far as I know that's declaration of zero elements array. And is there any way to trick it to make it work?

Comment: What language are you really using?  In C, that's valid.  In C++, it is not.

Comment: That's the thing, he seems to be using a weird combination of both

Comment: It is a common device in C to put a struct at the head of a memory block, then use the 0-length array to index into the block.

Comment: @DrewDormann no, it is not valid in C.

Comment: @ksi3m unfortunately the fix is changing the `[0]` to `[]` or `[1]`. If the MS Visual *"C"* compiler lets this pass another option would be to use *"C"* compiler to compile a file that includes this header and then interface from C++ into C there.